# How do I install PHP 5.3 on CentOS?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, centos

I have to install PHP 5.3 on my CentOS server. If I do `yum install php`, the base repository installs 5.1.6 which is too old for the applications I need to install. So I've been trying to use the [IUS](http://iuscommunity.org/About) repository, following the official instructions from IUS:

```
root@linuxbox ~]# wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/ius-release-1-2.ius.el5.noarch.rpm

root@linuxbox ~]# wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/epel-release-1-1.ius.el5.noarch.rpm

root@linuxbox ~]# rpm -Uvh ius-release*.rpm epel-release*.rpm
```

OK. Now I simply do `yum install php53`, etc. for all I need... but I get this error:

```
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Finished Transaction Test


Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/bin/php from install of php53u-cli-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
  file /usr/bin/php-cgi from install of php53u-cli-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
  file /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz from install of php53u-cli-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
  file /etc/php.ini from install of php53u-common-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64

Error Summary
-------------
```

I have no idea on how to solve this. I think I have to delete the base packages. However, as someone new to Linux, I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update**: Apparently RHEL 5.6 [includes PHP 5.3](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/5.6_Release_Notes/index.html), so this will be showing up natively for CentOS soon.

```
file /usr/bin/php from install of php53u-cli-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
file /usr/bin/php-cgi from install of php53u-cli-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
file /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz from install of php53u-cli-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-cli-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
file /etc/php.ini from install of php53u-common-5.3.4-3.ius.el5.x86_64 conflicts with file from package php-common-5.1.6-27.el5_5.3.x86_64
```

The problem here is that the packages you are installing have a different name (php53 instead of php), but they attempt to install the same files...hence the conflicts.  This isn't necessarily the best way to put the packages together, but I don't know if there are better packages available so we'll ignore that.

To remove your currently installed packages:

```
# yum remove php-cli php-common php
```

So, in general, `yum remove <list of packages>` will remove the packages.  And of course, `yum list installed` to see a list of installed packages (or `rpm -qa`).

Comment: hm yeah remove might be better than erase, since erase also removes dependencies.  Try the remove first, if that fails try erase.

Comment: `remove` and `erase` are synonymns, according to the `yum` man page under both CentOS and recent Fedora releases.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, although i didn't have to remove php but the first two in that list. To install php 5.3 i only need to yum install php53 right? There are alot of packages listed but i think that's the only important one right?

Comment: Definitely synonyms. Look in `yumcommands.py` if you doubt. :)

Comment: Probably.  Only you would know if your application requires any of the additional modules (e.g., xml support, ldap support, databases, and so forth).

Comment: i can't believe there is still no PHP 5.3 or even 5.2 in centos repos. screw this i'm gonna go with debian.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this has changed, as of January 13th, 2011. Red Hat has released version 5.6, and this includes PHP version 5.3 as a separate package (`php53`).

You have to remove the old PHP and then install PHP 5.3 separately. This sounds similar to your package from the IUS repository, but now it's official.

For more information, see [the Red Hat release notes](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html-single/5.6_Release_Notes/index.html#id2340523).

Note that this is just out from Red Hat, and there will be a little delay before this is available in CentOS. The RHEL 5.6 update looks relatively minor, though, so I shouldn't expect it to be too long.

Comment: yep. and 4 months later. it's still not in centos repos. :(

Comment: Yeah. :( https://lwn.net/Articles/435744/

Comment: It's available as of April, 2011. Whew. See [CentOS 5.6 Release Notes](http://wiki.centos.org/Manuals/ReleaseNotes/CentOS5.6#head-b896a8d3b5303f6b000c7f75a2d97d8966f14204)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the old versions of the packages before installing the new ones:

> yum erase php-cli php-comon

then try your yum install.

**Warning**: look at the list of changes that yum wants to make before committing, to make sure you are not removing other important packages.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, you need to uninstall the default php packages first.  Before going forward, keep in mind that other packages may have specific dependencies on the base versions.  Chances are, you will be fine, but just be forwarned that you may need to address other concerns later.

You should be able to do this by issuing

```
yum erase php-common php-cli
```

Followed by your

```
yum install php53
```

Answer (score 1):

CentOS 6 is now available, and includes PHP 5.3:

http://isoredirect.centos.org/centos/6/isos/x86_64/

Answer (score 1):

1. I had to remove `php-cli`, `php-common` and `php-dev` along with some dependencies but nothing else (MySQL, etc. were untouched.)
2. I installed the same packages in the PHP 5.3 flavor with dependencies and now everything is up and running. `phpinfo` confirms that I'm running PHP Version 5.3.3.
3. I restarted Apache and the site, running Joomla, just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue where "yum update php" would give me conflict errors.

Running "yum update" (update everything) did work for me though. Give that a try.

Also, realize that if you run "yum erase php" or "yum remove php", it may **remove all packages that depend on PHP**... which would probably include your Plesk or CPanel control panel if you have that installed. If I'm not mistaken, you would have to reinstall those, which could be a pain.

Comment: Yes, I have exactly that problem. To upgrade PHP, yum wants to delete Drupal, which is not really a dependency: it requires PHP to work, but it doesn't quite care what version of PHP, as it is PHP source and not a compiled program. Any way to uninstall PHP5.2 and have it leave Drupal alone?

Answer (score 0):

I have just solved this problem after much research, namely installing PHP 5.3.10 on CentOS 5.3. I had tried using several repositories, including the [Atomicorp repo](http://atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/PHP), but this broke plesk

I finally found the following steps works a treat, thought I share.

**BEGIN**

Download and enable REMI and EPEL repositories

```
cd ~
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-5.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-5*.rpm epel-release-5*.rpm

vi /etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo
```

**Change "enabled=0" to "enabled=1" under the "[remi]" heading**

You must remove php-sqlite2 or you will get a dependency error

```
yum remove php-sqlite2
```

Update PHP to the latest version 5.3.10 in this case

```
yum update php
```

Back up php.ini and enable newly-installed version

```
mv /etc/php.ini /etc/php.ini.old
mv /etc/php.ini.rpmnew /etc/php.ini
```

Back up my.cnf and enable newly-installed version

```
mv /etc/my.cnf /etc/my.cnf.old
mv /etc/my.cnf.rpmnew /etc/my.cnf
```

Install latest version of ioncube extension

```
wget http://downloads2.ioncube.com/loader_downloads/ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
tar -xvf ioncube_loaders_lin_x86-64.tar.gz
mv ioncube/* /usr/lib64/php/modules/

echo 'zend_extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/ioncube_loader_lin_5.3.so' > /etc/php.d/ioncube-loader.ini
```

You may also need to install php extensions, in this case I also needed to install the SOAP extension:

```
yum install php-soap
```

Restart services to make the changes take affect

```
service mysqld restart
service httpd restart
```

**DONE**

Cheers;
Mark