# installing php from source

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, centos

i have a centos5.5 server on which i want to host Magento. However i don't want to use a control panel but to do everything myself. The base repo on centos provides php 5.1.6 which is too old for the application to use.

If i download and compile from source the newest php, will i also have to install the newest apache and mysql? I wan't all the pieces to work well together. I am new at linux but i know enough to install these things from latest source. But say i install the new apache 2.2.17 which has document root at /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/ how do i tell php where that is, if you understand what i mean? Thanks for your help.

Comment: See: http://serverfault.com/questions/221251/how-do-i-install-php-5-3-on-centos/222034#222034

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't install php from a updated repository? I use [remi-enterprise](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en).

Comment: i'd love to but is there a repo that has all the updated components apache, mysql and php... i dont want to mix and match. I tried ius but it only has php and mysql not apache.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.x compatible with any version from apache or MySQL, I am now using the latest PHP with apache 2.2.x and MySQL 5.1.x with out any problems.