# Using SSH to upgrade from PHP 5.1.6 to PHP 5.3

Tags: php, ssh

I have a virtual server with PHP 5.1.6. How can I upgrade to PHP 5.3 using SSH?

Thanks in advance,

John

Comment: It depends on several aspects. What is your distribution/version?

Comment: It sounds like you are running Red Hat Enterprise Linux or CentOS 5.5. See: 

http://serverfault.com/questions/221251/how-do-i-install-php-5-3-on-centos/222034#222034

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the server operating system / linux flavour it might be as easy as:
yum update php
or 
apt-get install php

Be aware this will update you to the latest version of php not necessarily 5.3, also be aware this might break things to proceed with caution!

if your running a redhat based system you should also be able to find a PHP 5.3 RPM which you can install with rpm -uvh rpmname.rpm if you need a specific version of php that yum can't provide.

Comment: When I tried the yum update is said "yum: command not found"

Comment: in which case your probably not running a redhat based operating system try cat /etc/*-release and paste the result into your question.

Answer (score 0):

download the new version of php and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

Its depend in many things:

- What distro you have.
- What version of PHP you wont to use.
- Is that necessary, because some php
  versions 2.2.x some functions.

After you decide, you can login to your server using either ssh client such as [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty), or from command line and follow steps.